# Required field not present on all pages leading to problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a ‘Create’ page in my MVC3 application that has 4 input fields that are all required. I also have an ‘Edit’ page in which 3 of these 4 fields can be edited. I do not want to display the 4th field and want to maintain it at its initial value (the field is the date that the entry was created ).

I mark the 4th field as [Required] in the model then this causes the model to be declared as invalid in post action method of the Edit field. If I omit the [Required] annotation then someone can create a user with a null value for this 4th field.

How can I get around this problem?

[image: create]
[image: edit]

Model Code:

```
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Role { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayName("Insert Date")]
    public DateTime? InsertDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Active")]
    public bool ActiveInd { get; set; }
```

Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, ZUserRoleModel mod)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            // code removed

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(mod);

    }
```

Comment: You question it's not clear at least for me, could add some of your relevant code and explaint very short what's happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make that field as hidden in edit mode.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.EntryDate)
```

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work. When I save after editing, instead of returning to the Index page nothing happens. This is because I have a ModelState.IsValid test in the post action of my Edit method which is returned as false even if I included the HiddenFor line.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need an answer for this, but what you need to do in order for the

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.EntryDate )
```

to work, is pass an existing model into view. So let's assume that your action for getting the user data looks like this. ( You did not supply it, so I am not sure if this is right )

```
Public ActionResult GetUser(int UserID)
{
    ZUserRoleModel model = new ZUserRoleModel(UserID); 
    // Maybe this could go to your database and gather user
    // It would populate the correct data into a model object

    return View("Edit", model);
}
```

With combination of the hidden field, your view will be populated with the existing user information, and the hidden field will be populated with data, and it will be passed to your edit action.

NOTE: I wrote this without any kind of testing, but it should still work, or at the very least, I hope it points you in the right direction if you still need assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fluentvalidation:  http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

Have a rule that's something like

```
RuleFor(user => user.field4).NotEmpty().When(ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue <> "edit")
```